# Idiomatic ways to say something like "the starting time for the meeting is put off for one hour"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request, idiomatic-language

Suppose a meeting is scheduled at 8:00am but is postponed to 9:00am (I am not sure if "postpone to 9:00am" is idiomatic). I want to say something like

> The meeting  ______(some verb or phrase) one hour.

How many ways can I fill in ____?

Answer (score 3):

*Postpone* is most certainly the right expression.

> The meeting **has been postponed** one hour.
>
> The meeting **has been postponed** until 9:00.

The following are also possible, but less likely for any kind of *formal* announcement:

> has been **pushed back to** ...
>
> has been **delayed until** ...
>
> has been **rescheduled to/for** ...

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

> The meeting has been **deferred** until 9:00 AM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the verb **reschedule** which means to schedule again according to a different timetable. Source; https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reschedule.

- *The meeting is rescheduled to 9:00 pm*

Answer (score 0):

Some ways (the first is my favourite) are:

> The meeting has been **put back** one hour
>
> The meeting has been **put off for** one hour
>
> The meeting has been **delayed by** one hour

The next two are not quite there, they imply the meeting already started:

> The meeting has been **held up for** one hour
>
> The meeting has been **adjourned for** one hour

Comment: I would add "pushed back" (by) one hour