# "shift by 1 day" vs. "shift 1 day later"

Tags: verb-usage

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- All deadlines have been **shifted by 1 day** due to the ongoing COVID-19 pandemic.
- All deadlines have been **shifted 1 later** due to the ongoing COVID-19 pandemic.

or perhaps should I *shift* differently?

I want to use the verb *shift* (I am aware otherwise could have said "postpone by 1 day", for example).

Comment: Related question (not related to the answer you're looking for, but I think people who are searching and find your question might be interested in this other one) [Idiomatic ways to say something like “the starting time for the meeting is put off for one hour”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/142952/9161)

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways Thanks, interesting link!

Comment: Both are grammatical (if you don't forget the word *day* in the second), but I would definitely include *later* unless it is very clear from context.

Comment: @AntonSherwood thanks very much for your feedback. You are welcome to convert your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical (if you don't forget the word *day* in the second), but I would definitely include *later* unless it is very clear from context.